# Why do size of "*.ipa" files for different targets in one project are different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a project with 5 targets. 
Each target has its own settings and its own "*.xcassets" resource (spleshscreen images, background images). 
One target is a Test-Target with secret settings to change configs and it has access to all resources.

Why do size of "*.ipa" files (and size of app in TestFlight) are different, from 12 to 18 megabytes? 
And the size of the Test-Target ipa-file, which includes all of the resources, is not the biggest, only 15 megabytes.
I checked the "Copy bundle resources" of targets and there are no extra resources.

What's wrong with my project settings? Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Because their resource sizes differ from each other?

Comment: @Desdenova "Test-Target" includes all resources and it is not the biggest

Comment: You can download the ipa to your mac and open it and take a look what's going on inside the package. Is the binary larger? Are png's not as much compressed as in other versions? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to include different resources with different targets.

You can add a .zip extension to the .ipa file and look at the contents to see what differs.

Also, zip compression will vary depending on the data. It's common to see larger files compress down smaller than other, smaller files.

Comment: First: after unpacking the Test project got bigger. Secod:I found that the splashscreen for target is not stored in Assets.car and it was very big and not compressed. Thank you very mach for help.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious that there size will differ. Different targets not only include `.xcassets` but also complied code.

Comment: code in targets the same by 95%. I do not think that it increases the size of the application up to 50%

Answer (score 0):

some suggest：

- Be sure you **options** is same when create .ipa;  .ipa for AppStore, .ipa for Test, or allow AppStore crash log trace & bitCode will lead to different .ipa size.
- Check cocoaPods reference in different target.
- Check resources file, like .mp4, .xcassets, their size may multiplied zoom in, not simple copy & paste.
- Codes size may beyond your feeling, especially you have many MACRO, Apple will do some work for codes.